# Data validation with custom route issue (default url when errors occur)

Tags: validation, cakephp, routes

I'm building a user panel, and having some problems with data validation. As an example, the page where you change your password (custom validation rule comparing string from two fields (password, confirm password)):

Route:

```
Router::connect('/profile/password', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'profile_password'));
```

Controller:

```
function profile_password()
    {
    $this->User->setValidation('password'); // using the Multivalidatable behaviour
    $this->User->id = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');
    if (empty($this->data))
      {
      $this->data = $this->User->read();
      } else {
      $this->data['User']['password'] = $this->Auth->password($this->data['User']['password_change']);
      if ($this->User->save($this->data))
        {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Edytowano hasło.', 'default', array('class' => 'success'));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'profile'));
        }
      }
    }
```

The problem is, that when I get to `http://website.com/profile/password` and mistype in one of the fields, the script goes back to `http://website.com/users/profile_password/5` (5 being current logged users' id). When I type it correctly then it works, but I don't really want the address to change.

It seems that routes aren't supported by validation... (?) I'm using Cake 1.3 by the way.

Any help would be appreciated,
Paul

---

### EDIT 1:

Changing the view from:

```
echo $form->create(
  'User',
  array(
    'url' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'profile_password'),
    'inputDefaults' => array('autocomplete' => 'off')
    )
  );
```

to:

```
echo $form->create(
  'User',
  array(
    'url' => '/profile/password',
    'inputDefaults' => array('autocomplete' => 'off')
    )
  );
```

does seem to do the trick, but that's not ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the URL of the form in the `profile_password.ctp` view file.

Try the following code:

```
echo $this->Form->create('User', array('url' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'profile_password')));
```

Also, I think your form might be a little vulnerable. Try using Firebug or something similar to POST a `data[User][id]` to your action. If I'm right, you should be setting:

```
$this->data['User']['id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
```

instead of:

```
$this->User->id = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');
```

because your `id` field is set in `$this->data`.

HTH.

Comment: I added the view code in the question, still - that solution is not ideal. Could you please expand upon that thought on `$this->User->id`?